# Passing potential huge files in chunks to Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I have to pass potential huge files from an ASP.NET Core middle Server to an ASP.NET backend.

I can’t use the ASP.NET backend web API directly, I have to go over a MVC Controller.
Currently my middle Server gets the file in Chunks (and does some verification), saves it to disk and after it completes it rereads it in chunks to pass it forward.
Is there an easy way to pass the chunks without buffering the file?

I currently got this:
MVC Controler:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadChunk(IFormFile fileChunk, string chunkMetadata)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(chunkMetadata))
     {
          var metaDataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChunkMetadata>(chunkMetadata);
          ...
          AppendContentToFile(tempFilePath, fileChunk); //writes file with FileMode.Append,
     }
}
```

my upload to back end [Edit]:

```
public IHttpActionResult FileUpload(string fileUri)
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var configProvider = Resolve<IApplicationConfigurationProvider>();
            var uploadRootDir = configProvider.TemporaryFileUploadPath;
            var streamProvider = new MultipartStreamProvider(uploadRootDir);

            // If the file is huge and is not split into chunks, the 'ReadAsMultipartAsync' call 
            // takes as long as full file has been copied
            var readResult = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).Result;
            var fileSvc = Resolve<IFileService>();
            string targetFilePath = string.Empty;

            foreach (MultipartFileData fileData in streamProvider.FileData)
            {
                ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition;
                string fileName = contentDisposition.FileName;

                if (!GetFileName(fileName, out var targetFileName))
                {
                    return BadRequest($"ContentDisposition.FileName must match 'file' of URI-query! Actual: {targetFileName}");
                }

                var rawSourceFileInfo = new FileInfo(targetFileName);
                if (contentDisposition.Size.HasValue && contentDisposition.Size.Value > 0)
                {
                    if (!fileSvc.CreateNewFilePath(fileUri, new PathOptions(true), out var validFileFullPath))
                    {
                        return BadRequest($"Unable to create physical-path from fileId='{fileUri}'");
                    }

                    targetFilePath = validFileFullPath.FullName;
                    fileSvc.AddChunk(validFileFullPath.FullName, contentDisposition.Size.Value, fileData.LocalFileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("File upload must set a valid file-length in ContentDisposition");
                }
            }

            return Ok(targetFilePath);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("File upload must be a 'IsMimeMultipartContent'");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        LogError(error, "FileUpload");
        return InternalServerError(error);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

[Edit]
my not  working call from client to back end:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#uploadImage").on('change', (function (e) {
            // append file input to form data
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('uploadImage');
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('uploadImage', file);

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/service/filestore/v1/upload?fileUri=someText",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 'invalid') {
                        // invalid file format.
                        $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
                    }
                    else {
                        // view uploaded file.
                        $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();
                        $("#form")[0].reset();
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $("#err").html(e).fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }));
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you do with XML instead of JSON?  The XmlReader can read huge Xml files.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at how to [upload large files with streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming-1) which is explained as: "The file is received from a multipart request and directly processed or saved by the app", so you can directly process it by rerouting it to your backend

Comment: @jdweng I don't think the OPs problem lies with them not being able to read the entire file at once, but them trying to keep memory usage down by splitting the file into chunks and uploading them one after another, instead of reading the whole file to memory and uploading it at once

Comment: @MindSwipe : My solution would reduce memory.  How would you propose to split a JSON into pieces?  You would need to read the entire file before splitting which will not accomplish what the OP is asking.

Comment: @jdweng correct me if I'm wrong, but your comment implies that your solution is to simply transmit an XML instead of a JSON. That wouldn't reduce memory usage, at best the memory usage would stay the same. I'm not suggesting splitting a JSON file, OP doesn't even mention JSON files (they use JsonConvert to deserialize metadata, not the actual data/ file), I'm suggesting OP streams their file, which can directly be streamed to the second ASP.NET application instead of saving to disk and reading again

Comment: @jdweng JSON.Net also works with streams - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage

Comment: What kinds of validation are you doing? (= do you need to parse the file?) Can you change the backend server api? (multipart form data is not the best option)

Comment: I have problems calling my backend directly since your sample uses “async Task<IActionResult>” and ASP.NET CORE the backend I have is a IHttpActionResult function with ASP.NET 4.8. I would prefer not changing the backend itself. At least the framework has to stay on 4.8 and not core. @MindSwipe

Comment: My Validation only affects metadata, I do not necessary need my middle Server but I would prefer to not change my backend. However, if it is necessary I can as  long as it stays asp.net 4.8 @Christoph Lütjen.